# IOS Image disappear on selecting another event

Tags: objective-c, ios8

Hi i am getting image from gallery by UIImagePickerController and shows on my view controller, i have textfield also when i enter text in textfield my image disappear. Please help me what is issue with this. my UIImagePickerController delegate method is

```
   -(IBAction)btnBackAction:(id)sender{
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}

-(IBAction)imageactoin:(id)sender{

    UIImagePickerController *pickerController = [[UIImagePickerController alloc]
                                                 init];
    pickerController.delegate = self;
    [self presentModalViewController:pickerController animated:YES];

}
#pragma mark UIImagePickerControllerDelegate

- (void) imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker
         didFinishPickingImage:(UIImage *)image
                   editingInfo:(NSDictionary *)editingInfo
{
    self.imageView.image=image;

    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}

@end
```

please help me whats issue that my image not disappear by selecting another event like textfield.

Comment: what is this self.imageView? did you manually create this UIImageView or is this the default one?

Comment: thisis my image view where i save it after getting from gallery @property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView* imageView;

Comment: Can you edit the answer with full code of your ViewController?

Comment: edited .. i just get image from gallery and show it on self.imageview i also have textfield in same view when i enter text in textfields it disappear..

Answer (score -1):

The below delegate method is deprecated from iOS 3.0

```
 - (void) imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker
             didFinishPickingImage:(UIImage *)image
                       editingInfo:(NSDictionary *)editingInfo
```

You have to use this one,

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {

    UIImage *chosenImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage];
    self.imageView.image = chosenImage;

    [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
}
```

Comment: Have you set <UINavigationControllerDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate> delegates in your class??

Comment: yes your method not working but above my method working fine but my problem was that my image disappera when i touch another field like textfield it could not remain save